# Angualr2 how can send data from one controller to other wthout url parameter like $state.go()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to pass parameter from one controller to other but I don't want to pass in url (need to hidden)I tried to pass like

```
this.router.navigate(['/collections/'+this.name], {id: this.id});
```

but on other controller I am not able to access it I also tried

```
    {
      path: 'collection/:city',
      component: Component,
      data : {id : null}
    }
```

but here how can I pass the id dynamic because in routing file I don't have the id value can it be pass from component.

In angulajs1.5 we use params hash to hide id from url.

```
$state.go('collection', {id: 10})

 state('collection', {
    url : '/collection',
    params : {
        id : null,
    },
    templateUrl : templatesDir + 'collection.html',
    controller : 'collectionController',
})
```

So is there any same way in angularjs2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create singleton object, to share it between more than one component.

1. Use as Service. @injector in Angular2. 
   [@injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)
2. Create [static members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) in one class and access them in other class by using class name there.

These two ways.

Answer (score 0):

In order to share data between controllers, you can store it in a factory/service. A factory can hold your data since it's a singleton object(only until refresh).

Best practice to store in a factory is to use getter/setter objects.

Go through this link for other ways to do this

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: It's not related to data sharing I want to pass some parameter in hidden way rather than url.
As we use $state.go('collection', {id: 10})

#####
state('collection', {
        url : '/collection',
        params : {
            id : null,
        },
        templateUrl : templatesDir + 'collection.html',
        controller : 'collectionController',
    })
Here the id will be hidden from path param.